# Can't find classic asp configuration option in iis 8.5

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-8.5

I followed [instructions](http://jwcooney.com/2013/12/30/enabling-classic-asp-on-iis8-windows-server-2012/) on enabling classic asp on iis8 windows server 2012 and the site started working.  Now I want to configure classic asp settings.  Instructions say `In IIS, click your Web site. Click the ASP option in the main window` but I can't find the option anywhere. What could I be missing?

Comment: I'd like for -1 folks to keep in mind that I searched online for an explanation prior to figuring out the fix.  Had this QA been available I would not have wasted time trying to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I gave up and rebooted the computer and the Classic ASP icon appeared.  When all else fails, reboot the computer.